# MVC 4:How to display blank textbox for model property of integer when integer value 0..?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using variable in model like

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"\d{5}-?(\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Enter only 5 digit numbers.")]
public int? Zipcode { get; set; }
```

In View I am using

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Shipping.Zipcode)
```

I need to use only in `@Html.DisplayFor`.

Comment: do you want to replace the label with textbox if the value is null in view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind your  @Html.DisplayFor in span for example like

```
   <span id="check">
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Zipcode)
        </span>
```

and than you can apply jquery to do achieve your scenario

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($("#check").text().trim() === "0") {
            $("#check").html("<input type='text' value='' name='test' id='test'>");
        }
    }); </script>
```

Comment: Or you could do it correctly and use `@if(Model.Shipping.Zipcode.Value == 0) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Shipping.Zipcode) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Shipping.Zipcode } else { @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Shipping.Zipcode) }`